# bricked verizon lg g2 vs980

Tags: unbricking, verizon, lg-g2

i have a rooted lg g2 vs980 and it accidentally installed a software update and now i get some kind of security boot error, it flashes to fast for me to read exactly what it says, but after the lg logo it only goes to black screen. I think it is bricked. I have tried hard reset but this does not work i also cannot enter recovery or download mode.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't bricked totally.

Security Error occurs when you have stock, locked bootloader and modified core Android system files and/or recovery/x-boot/u-boot partitions.

Locked bootloader checks for signatures of some files and these partitions. The best approach would be to take LG Flash Tool, get original KDZ for your LG, extract `recovery.img`, `u-boot.img`, `x-boot.img` and `boot.img` partitions and flash them with `fastboot`.

Try experimenting with VOL-UP/DOWN keys to get to fastboot.

You will probably want to use this command:
`fastboot flash <partition> <file>`

You need:

1. [LG Flash Tool and KDZ extractor](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2600575)
2. KDZ file for your model (search XDA-dev for it)

Good luck!

Comment: i will try that thank you so so so so so much